# How to send my project to a colleague?

Tags: rubymine

My colleague and myself are fairly new to RubyMine and to Ruby. We use WinXP Pro.

I want to zip a small Ruby (non-Rails) project and either email it to my colleague or copy it to a share. Note that we are not currently using a single repository for RubyMine projects.

---

Edited:  Please ignore everything above the line. It seems to be causing some generous responders to waste their time. I apologize for that.

Assume the post starts below this line.

---

I have no internet connection. I want to zip a small Ruby (non-Rails) test project, copy it to a floppy, and deliver it by hand to a friend. My friend has no internet connection.

I would like to confirm that all I need to do is to zip everything including, and below, the project root in Windows Explorer. (I'm assuming that the "project root" is the folder that contains the "gemfile".)

I'm assuming that the gemfile.lock will force my colleague's gems to match mine, even if one of his gems is more up to date than mine.

I'm assuming that the contents of RM's "External Libraries" will be recreated on my colleague's RM, without my needing to include these files in the ZIP.

I would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a version control system like git or svn.

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, we currently have no repository for RM projects. We need to prove the concept first. My company use VSS, and they have no intention of paying for a license for me without some justification. So, for the moment, it's zips or nothing.

Comment: a common Dropbox-sync folder. ;)